# Google Drive SDK (PHP Client Library) - Upload file but unreadable on the Google Drive UI

Tags: php, google-docs, google-docs-api, google-drive-api

Here is my code to upload a file:

```
private function addFile(File $file, $folderProject, User $user) {

    $fileToUpload = new Google_DriveFile();
    $fileToUpload->setTitle($file->getName());

    //set mime type
    $fileToUpload->setMimeType($file->getMimeType());

    //build parent and set id
    $parent = new Google_ParentReference();
    $parent->setId($folderProject->getId());

    //set parent to file
    $fileToUpload->setParents(array($parent));

    $data = file_get_contents($file->getPath());

    $createdFile = $this->service->files->insert($fileToUpload, array(
            'data' => $data,
            'mimeType' => $file->getMimeType(),
    ));

}
```

---

When I upload for example a docx using this PHP code the file append to be unreadable on the Google Drive website (it shows up the XML structure of the docx) and it is showing up like this in my Google Drive folder:

[image: unreadable]

And when i try to upload a docx directly through Google Drive UI it showing up like this (what i want):
[image: readable]

> I'm pretty sure that the problem is coming from the fact the Google
>   Drive UI tries to open the file in a different way because i uploaded
>   it through my app, but i don't want that :)

(i have the same problem with other kind of files)

---

I tried to set the parameter `'convert' = true` in the array but then i got this error during the upload:

> ..convert=true&uploadType=multipart&key=AI39si49a86oqv9fhb9yzXp7FCWL-cSqwFiClHZ‌​qS3Y3r9Hw8ujtSNlZEWZyFKBp_id7LUyFaZTJ97pMeb0XqHznycK7JJ9o_Q:
>   (500) Internal Error

Documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/insert

=> But anyway i don't think to convert is the right solution, i just want to be able to see the content as if i uploaded the file through the Google Drive UI

---

If i open the docx from my Google Drive Sync folders and I edit and save it, I will be able to see it through the Google Drive UI (showing with the W logo)

Comment: Is the file uploaded via the Google Drive UI converted to a Google docs? I'm asking because I don't have a .docx file to test this with, but if this is the case, you can reproduce this by providing the `convert=true` query parameter with your insert request: add `'convert' => TRUE` to the `array`.

Comment: Mh no i got this error then: Error calling POST ...convert=true&uploadType=multipart&key=AI39si49a86oqv9fhb9yzXp7FCWL-cSqwFiClHZqS3Y3r9Hw8ujtSNlZEWZyFKBp_id7LUyFaZTJ97pMeb0XqHznycK7JJ9o_Q: (500) Internal Error, forgot to reply to you yes it is converted from the Google Drive UI or even with the Google Drive App for Windows (to sync folders), i mean it is still a .docx but you can read it through the Google Drive UI ;)

Comment: @Alain This might be a bug no?

Answer (score 0):

I also getting the same problem.

But the difference is that , I am uploading pdf and able to view pdf in google drive UI.

I need to automatically convert it to google doc format by api code after adding new pdf.

If I change   $mimeType = 'application/vnd.google-apps.document'; then got below error
https://www.googleapis.com/upload/drive/v2/files?convert=true&uploadType=multipart: (400) Bad Request

if I add optional parameter

```
$createdFile = $service->files->insert($file, array(
  'data' => $data,
  'mimeType' => $mimeType,
'convert' => TRUE
));
```

Then no change , only pdf upload no conversion takes place.

do u have any suggestion , where I need to exactly add for convert parameter ?